# Automatic pytest.mark decoration based on fixture

Tags: python, pytest, python-decorators

Let's say I have a pytest fixture established in my conftest.py file that looks like:

```
def live_fixture():
    # network access here...
    pass
```

I use this same fixture in many test functions, say that test_spam.py has some test functions:

```
@pytest.mark.live
def test_one(live_fixture):
    assert 1


def test_one():
    assert 2 

@pytest.mark.live
def test_three(live_fixture):
    assert 3
```

I use the `@pytest.mark.live` decoration on the first and third test functions because those two tests both depend on the fixture `live_fixture`, which goes out over the network and does stuff. Rationale: I like having a reliable subset of my tests pass offline, such that e.g.

```
py.test -m "not live" test_spam.py --blockage
```

will reliably pass (using the nifty [pytest-blockage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-blockage) module to enforce the no-network-access restriction).

But writing out the `@pytest.mark.live` decoration on each test function which uses the `live_fixture` here is tedious and error-prone. Is there some way to have that fixture declare that any test function which uses it should automatically have `@pytest.mark.live` decoration applied to it, or some way to detect inside file test_spam.py that `test_one` and `test_three` use that `live_fixture` and thus should be effectively decorated `@pytest.mark.live`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found another plausible solution, by trying to dig out how pytest.mark works.

I found class Node has a method "add_marker", which should be the exact method which implement feature pytest.mark. And class Item is extended from Node.

So my solution is:

1. Trying to find if the fixture is used by the test.
2. Let Item object of the test call add_marker

Example: Add following method in conftest.py

```
def pytest_itemcollected(item):
    """ we just collected a test item. """
    if 'live_fixture' in item.fixturenames:
        item.add_marker('live')
```

I hope at least my answer would inspire somebody to think of a more decent way.

Comment: This is a really neat solution, thanks! I was also hoping to automatically apply `pytest.mark.skipif` decoration onto any test functions using `live_fixture`, do you know if that's possible as well?

Comment: @JoshKupershmidt Yes, add_marker also takes `MarkDecorator` object as input, and `pytest.mark.skipif` returns a `MarkDecorator` object. So all you need to do is to create the skipif marker and add it. For example: `marker = pytest.mark.skipif(condition, reason='')`, then `item.add_marker(marker)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fooled around with this a bit more and got something very rough working. I define a function like this:

```
import sys, inspect, pytest

def mark_live_fixtures(module_name):
    testfunctions = [obj for name,obj
                     in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[module_name])
                     if (inspect.isfunction(obj) and
                         name.startswith('test') and name != 'testall')]

    for func in testfunctions:
        if 'live_fixture' in inspect.getargspec(func).args:
            func = pytest.mark.live(func)
```

And then I'm able to stick a call to `mark_live_fixtures(__name__)` at the bottom of a test file, and it seems to apply `pytest.mark.live` decoration to all test functions in that module using `live_fixture`. But there are at least two problems with this approach:

1. I believe this would only work with test functions defined at the top-level of a test module, I doubt it would work with test functions inside a [test class](https://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html#grouping-multiple-tests-in-a-class).
2. Any test functions which have e.g. `@mock.patch` or other common test decoration will **not** have proper argument introspection available to inspect.getargspec (this is the reason the [decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module exists), so they would not get decorated as expected.

This is admittedly a bit ugly, maybe someone has a cleaner solution?